# It's possible to use Environment functions in gulp-nunjucks-render?

Tags: gulp, nunjucks

I want to use something like [Nunjucks render](https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render#nunjucks-rendercontext), but with another function. For example [addglobal](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#addglobal).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical other way to add variables would be to use [Nunjucks Enviorment's](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#environment) and use addGlobal.

Gulp nunjucks render is built so that it handles it's own environments (as default nunjucks behavior), and as you stated you can pass variables as an object on the render call.

That being said, it does give you the ability to control your own environment it looks like. After some tinkering I was able to create my own environemnt using:

```
var nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');

var nunEnv = new nunjucksRender.nunjucks.Environment([loaders], [opts]);
```

At that point you can handle it manually as per the Enviroment doc listed above, and use addGlobal as you desire. It will be a bit more work though then the default usage described here, https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render